# ネストさせずに配列を独立して連続作成する方法　について

Tags: ruby

下記、3つの配列を生成します。

```
r = []
3.downto(1) do |x|
  k = gets.split(' ')　　　#数字・半角スペース・数字　と入力
  k = k.map { |v| v.to_i}
  r << k
end
p r　　　　　　　　        　#=>　[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

要素の操作例

```
p r[0][1] ** 2　　　     　#=>　4
```

▼本当は `m = [1, 2]`, `n = [3, 4]`, `o = [5, 6]` とできれば要素の操作がわかりやすいと思っていますが、やり方・可不可がわかりません。
　ご教授いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

【追記】
　例えば、複数人の買い物金額を、雑貨、食料品、書籍の順に
m:1000 1100 1200　　n:1300 1400 1500　　o:1600 1700 1800
　と入力した後で、(これも例ですが、1100に2日分とか3日分ということで2や3〜を掛けたり掛けなかったりして)各人の合計を出す、というものです。
　r = [[1000, 1100, 1200], [1300, 1400 1500], [1600, 1700, 1800]]
よりも
　m = [1000, 1100, 1200]　n = [1300, 1400, 1500]　o = [1600, 1700, 1800]
の方がわかりやすい（r[0][1] と m[1]）し可読性も増すと思われます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問の内容がよくわからないのでお聞きしたいのですが、どういう「要素の操作」をしたいのでしょうか。m, n, oを使ってこういう風に操作をしたい、というコードが（動かなくてもいいので）あれば、追記していただきたいです。

Comment: コード部分を選択して編集画面上の方にある {} ボタンを押すことで、簡単にコードブロックの装飾ができます。お試しください。

Comment: 複数人というのが、少人数に限られているのなら、別々の配列にしても良いと思います。

Comment: １０００人の買い物のために、配列を１０００個定義して、それぞれを処理するコードを書くのは大変ですし、読みにくいのでお勧めしません。（238個目の配列の処理だけ抜けていた、なんていうのを見つけるのは難しいですからね）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

インスタンス変数(`@m` `@n` `@o` など)に対してなら以下のようにできます。

```
array_name = 'm'

3.times do
  instance_variable_set('@' + array_name, gets.split(' '))
  array_name.succ!
end

p @m
p @n
p @o
```

ローカル変数(`m` `n` `o` など)の場合は、事前に定義されている名前でないと無理だったと思います。

```
array_name = 'm'

m = nil
n = nil
o = nil
b = binding

3.times do
  b.local_variable_set(array_name, gets.split(' '))
  array_name.succ!
end

p m
p n
p o
```